# Do I need to explicitly turn-off unused modules like wi-fi or hdmi to conserve power?

Tags: power-management

I just got my first PI4 to be used as a NAS with OpenMediaValut and USB3 HDD. It is connected to my router directly via ethernet. I'd like to make sure it is not consuming more power than needed for the task.

Do I need to explicitly switch-off things like wi-fi / bluetooth / hdmi (I never even set them up)?

Does it make sense to turn-off led lights?

Is it reasonable to assume, that something as mature as OpenMediaValut will use USB3 HDD in an optimized manner?

P.S. before anyone suggests, I've seen

[How to achieve Low Power Consumption on Raspberry Pi via Software and Hardware control](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33723/how-to-achieve-low-power-consumption-on-raspberry-pi-via-software-and-hardware-c)

[How to make the Raspberry Pi consume less power](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32562/how-to-make-the-raspberry-pi-consume-less-power)

but I'm not sure if they still apply to PI4