# RPi model 2 - USB ports receive no power

Tags: pi-2, hardware, power-supply, usb-power, cable

The USB ports on my *Raspberry Pi 2 model B V1.1* do not receive any power. I measured the USB pins with a multi-meter, which should have 5V, but have none.

- I tried different power supplies, which work properly on another RPi 2.
- I measured C97, C98, C99 and C100, all of which receive no power.
- The Pi boots properly, the GPIO pins do have 5V on them.
- The USB peripherals work fine on other devices.
- I tried different SD cards with different Linux distros.

I tried looking for any polyfuses for the USB ports, but I cannot find them for the RPi 2.

Comment: There are no polyfuses See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations) for some info

Answer (score 2):

Looks like hardware is damaged for some reason?

Also, have a look at these links:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=93463

[Disabling USB ports](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8448/disabling-usb-ports)

Apparently, there are commands to turn off USB power as mentioned in these threads. Maybe you could try some to enable the USB power.

Comment: It's worth noting that at least some of those commands will kill power to both the USB sockets and the ethernet socket. That would make it impossible to issue any further commands to the Pi - use with caution, and make sure you've got an exit strategy in case of disasters.

Comment: @goobering How's reboot for an exit strategy?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Good question! I'm about 90% sure it'll reset itself after rebooting, but my Linux-Fu is fairly miserable and I don't particularly want to be the one to test it. Bricking a Pi isn't on my to-do list for the afternoon.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was an option I did not try yet. Sadly it did not work for me.

Comment: Sometimes I find that the QC on power supply cables are not consistent and my occasional power problems can be fixed by swapping out the cable.  I hope your Pi itself is OK.