# Disable all usb except edimax dongle (7811Un)

Tags: pi-3, usb

I am using raspberry pi 3 and edimax Wi-Fi dongle. I have some rules defined inside /etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules like what to do when edimax wifi dongle is connected/disconnected

Vendor id I obtained after running **lsusb** is as below

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
```

Accordingly I added the below rules

```
KERNELS=="[1-9]*-[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="7392", RUN+="/home/pi/dongleon.sh &"
KERNELS=="[1-9]*-[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="remove", ATTRS{idVendor}=="7392", RUN+="/home/pi/dongleoff.sh &"
```

Now I don't want any other USB plugged into raspberry pi ports to work. I want to allow only edimax Wi-Fi dongle and block all other usb devices.

Can some one please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: isn't the ethernet port on the USB bus?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this guide](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/plug-and-prey-malicious-usb-devices#3.2_Locking_down_Linux_using_UDEV) and [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63199/how-to-disable-usb-devices-based-on-vendor-id-in-linux-environment) on Unix SE.

First, add a rule to disable all USB devices by default:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'for host in /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*; do echo 0 > $host/authorized_default; done'"
```

Then, add a rule to enable that particular dongle by vendor ID:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTR{idVendor}=="7392" RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo 1 >/sys$DEVPATH/authorized'"
```

You should also keep the rules you have if you need to run custom scripts when the dongle is plugged in.